# Cannot send arabic SMS twilio

Tags: java, android, twilio, twilio-api

I want to send an sms that contains arabic letter but when I send the sms. It is being sent like this: `???????`
Is there any solution to this problem?
Thanks.

Code:

```
try{

String twilioSID="AC2be050f87d26aa4b44186c50f6e610e2";
 String twilioSecret="abc123";



                String urlStr = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+twilioSID+"/Messages.json";

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);
                String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(
                        ("AC2be050f87d26aa4b44186c50f6e610e2" + ":" + "abc123").getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);


                httppost.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);
                String randomCode2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5);
                String getmob = getIntent().getStringExtra("mob");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+1334254136528"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", getmob));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "كود السحب على الهدية \n" +
                        "("+randomCode2+")\n" +
                        "احتفظ بيه"));

                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairs));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a few things I need to tell you here.

First, please never share your Auth Token publicly. With your Account SID and Auth Token a malicious user could abuse your account. I recommend you immediately [change your Auth Token](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them) to avoid any attacks.

Next up, you have tagged this Android, so I assume you are doing this in an Android application. You should not make calls directly to the Twilio API from an Android application. This is because to do so you need to include your Auth Token. In this case a malicious user could decompile your Android app and extract your Auth Token and use it to abuse your account. Instead, you should build a server application that can store your credentials and make requests to the Twilio API. Here's a blog post on [how to send an SMS from Android with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html).

Finally, for when you come to build your server side integration to Twilio, you are using the wrong API endpoint. The URL you build up is:

```java
String urlStr = "https://"+twilioSID+":"+twilioSecret+"@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+twilioSID+"/SMS/Messages";
```

This is using the very old and deprecated `/SMS/Messages` endpoint. Instead, you should be using the more recent [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource), with a URL like this:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json
```

The `/SMS/Messages` endpoint did not handle characters outside of ASCII, but the [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource) can handle any unicode characters.

Since you will be building a server-side integration, I can recommend that you use one of the [Twilio helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) which make it easier to make requests to the right resource.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for sharing my twilio secret, But unfortunately it still sends "?" rather than the actual word. I have no idea why.I have changed my URL to `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json
`, but still no change. Any ideas?!

Comment: I was just able to send 'كود السحب على الهدية' to myself using the [Twilio CLI](https://twil.io/cli) and it arrived on my phone correctly. Can you update your question with the code you are using now, please? Also, are you running this on Android or a server?

Comment: I am running it on Android, I will update to a server later. I am using `twilio-8.7.0-with-dependancies.jar` by the way, And I didn't change anything in my code except that I used `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json` instead of the first one!

Comment: Ok, there's no point in fixing this on the Android device, as you cannot use that for production. See how you go implementing it on the server and let me know if you have any problems there.